# Placing a converted value inside a rich:simpleTogglePanel label

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, converters

I'm in a situation where I need to place a date value inside a [rich:simpleTogglePanel](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_simpleTogglePanel.html) label. The problem is I need to converter the date prior to displaying it, using

```
<h:outputText converter="#{dateTimeConverter}" value="#{date}" />
```

Then I need to place another string in front of it. Unfortunately label is an attribute and only takes a string.

Is there anyway to do this? Any undocumented label facet? I'm using Richfaces version 3.3.3.Final.

Comment: Which version of RichFaces do you use (RichFaces 4 doesn't seem to have a simpleTogglePanel)? Could you post the code you're using right now (simpleTogglePanel doesn't seem to have a label facet, so how do you set it)?

Comment: @Thomas, I clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any undocumented facets, thus using plain Java EL you'd have to provide a getter that returns the formatted date string.

Another option would be to use [JBoss EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.0.GA/reference/en/html/elenhancements.html), which is an extension to the standard Java EL and allows to call methods with parameters.

You then could do something like this: `label="#{dateTimeConverter.convert(date)}"`.

We use this a lot and it works like a charm.

Note the following:

- you'd have use facelets with JBoss EL, JSP doesn't work quite well
- although JBoss EL is part of JBoss Seam, it can be used in a [standalone way](https://rogerkeays.com/blog/el-function-parameters-with-jboss-el)

Comment: I ended up just formatting it on the backend before display. As much as I don't like to do formatting in the backend code in this it was the most straight forward way.